# How can I pull the list a user's project through Gitlab API by Laravel?

Tags: laravel, gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm very new at Gitlab API. I'm using it for my project.
Well, I have one local Gitlab server with many projects (Or maybe it's call "repository") in there.

So, I want to use Laravel to pull some parameter that is list a user's projects by using Gitlab API. Honestly, I have no idea to start this work.

I already read the Gitlab documentation but still can't get it clearly. What I want is the image as below. Could you guys guide me to get this? Thank you very much.

[This is what I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHDa2.png)

Comment: What have you do so far to achieve this ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen I just had done with setting up the Gitlab server and Laravel. Both of these can work together well now. But the problem is I really don't know how to pull some information from Gitlab API for show them up to my Laravel website, such as list of repositories, and the versions that committed from the users.

Comment: You just need to hit the api provided from the Gitlab, you want me to help in that ?

Comment: Surely, I need your help. But I don't get it clearly about "hit the api provided from the Gitlab" that you said. Could you explain me about that briefly please? I'm so much glad for your help.

Comment: Sure, Can you share the gitlab api url that you try, I have worked in github api, which gives output [like this](https://api.github.com/users/sulthanallaudeen) Can you tell which api gives [your expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHDa2.png). So that i can help you on that

Comment: Sure, I will send the information that you need via your email (sa@sulthanallaudeen.com << I get from your profile detail. Is this right email?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html) is the GitLab api to read the projects

You can do [file-get-contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to read something from api

So, finally as per your gitlab configuration you can do like this to read all the projects

```
$url = "http://yoururl/api/v4/projects";
$homepage = file_get_contents($url);
echo $homepage;
```

Hope this helps you.